# how refer to a local variable share same name of a global variable in C?

Tags: c, global-variables, scope, local-variables

for example

```
#include<stdio.h>

int foo = 100;

int bar()
{
    int foo;
    /* local foo = global foo, how to implemented? */
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int result = bar();
    return 0;
}
```

I think in the function bar, calling foo directly will just get the global foo. How can I refer the local foo? I know in C++, there is this pointer. However, does C has something similar?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: May be you can refer to the answer by Ouah : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183899/how-to-print-value-of-global-variable-and-local-variable-having-same-name

Answer (score 16):

No, by declaring `foo` in `bar()`, you have taken the global `foo` out of scope.  Inside `bar()` when you refer to `foo` you get the local variable.

Comment: I tried and looks like you are right. Is there any way to refer to the "global foo" inside bar() then?

Comment: change the name of your local variable is the normal solution

Comment: just doesn't look elegant, but if that is the only way, I can do that

Comment: I don't know why the first answer is gone. I think it was a good one, tried using {extern int foo; temp = foo}, it works, Thanks to whoever come up with it then. To David: so this is not possible. However, I am still wondering if there is more elegant way.

Comment: Conversely, in C, there is no way to refer to the global variable `foo` from inside `bar()` - at least, not once the declaration of the local variable `foo` is complete.  In C++, you could use `::foo` but that is not available in C.

Comment: the other answerer deleted the answer because you asked how to access the local variable. C doesn't really lend itself to scope resolution and namespace like features. Just choose a different name is the elegant solution.

Comment: to Jonathan: you are right, I will agree that there is no a "direct" way in C. Yes, ::foo works for C++

Comment: @AlfredZhong If you really have a specific variable name you want to use, i.e., it best describes the data being stored, the most elegant way I have found is to add an underscore '_' character to the beginning or end of the local variable name. For example: `static void * address; void init(void * _address) { address = _address; }`