# How to access a global pointer within a function, containing another pointer with the same name?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access a shadowed global variable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c)

How to access a global pointer within a function, containing another pointer with the same name and type.

Ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ptr = "Hello World";

int main(void)
{
//char ptr = 'a';
 char *ptr = "Global is over written";

printf("%s", ptr); //Here i am trying to print the value of global ptr i.e, "Hello World".

return 0;
}
```

Comment: they aren't the same type...

Comment: @Mike if they were same type still you can not access global one...it always return local one's value

Comment: @Mr.32 - right, my point was the question doesn't match the code. It wasn't meant to be an answer.

Comment: @Mike see now question match with code..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing `%s` do `%c`you will get ``a'`

Also you should know about `instance member hiding` It's also called `shadowing`.

In layman language you can say : At nearer we got the variable ,we will not look for farther

If `local` and `global` has same identifier then local will come into picture first

If you want to know more about how to access global variable in local scope

In C++ use `::` scope resolution operator

For C visit the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183899/how-to-print-value-of-global-variable-and-local-variable-having-same-name)

Comment: He wants to know why he cant access the global variable.

Comment: See the link It might help you

Comment: @Nick: See my new answer ,now Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the global variable because the local variable *shadows* the global one, they are both defined in the same scope and have the same name. Change its name if you want to access both. Read more about [Variable Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 0):

You can get global value by this way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ptr = "Hello World";
char *getGlobalPtr()
{
return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
char ptr = 'a';
printf("%s", getGlobalPtr()); //Here i am trying to print the value of global ptr i.e, "Hello World".

return 0;
}
```