# the defined variable is different

Tags: c

why is the variable in the average function is different from the same variable in the main function? I do not know how to solve it because I'm just learning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  SIZE (sizeof(number)/sizeof(int))

int number[] = {5,65,84,25,644,2};

int average(int *number)
{
    printf("size = %ld\n",SIZE);
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=SIZE ;i++)
    {
    sum += number[i];
    }
    return sum/SIZE;
}

int main()
{
printf("average : %d\n",average(number));
printf("number of elements: %ld\n", SIZE);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: If one of the answered given solved your problem, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a macro (i.e. `#define ...`) to specify `SIZE`. The macro is expanded "textually" wherever you make use of it, and it is interpreted in the respective context, i.e. it's meaning depends on where you place it.

So in main, `number` as part of your macro refers to the global variable `number`, whereas in the context of function `average`, it refers to the function argument `number` (which hides the equally named global variable).

Anyway, it's impossible to deduce any array size from a pointer variable. You'll have to pass the number of elements as an extra argument.

Comment: WoW! I didn't see the macro mistake. +1 for that

Comment: you're welcome. If it helped, don't forget to mark one of the answers as "acceped" by pressing the green arrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within `main`, `number` is a global variable which is an array.  So `sizeof(number)` gives you the size of the whole array in bytes.

In the `average` function however, `number` is a parameter to the function and has type `int *`.  So `sizeof(number)` in that case gives you the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.

Either don't pass a parameter and just use the global, or pass the size of the array as a separate parameter to the function.

Comment: Is this an example of why using globals can be problematic?

Comment: @RandomDavis In a way yes, as it illustrates how a variable at an inner scope can mask a variable with the same name at a higher scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a global variable `number` which is an array.

In the function `average` , you defined another variable with the same name/identifier `number` (although of different type i.e. a pointer).

Now, when you use `number` inside the main function you are actually using the pointer `number` and not the global variable `number`. This is also known as variable hiding.

If you want to use the global variable change the name of the argument of the `average` function to something else or you can go the hard way and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12183931/5757160).

Happy Coding;)