# How to access global variable when there is a local and global conflict

Tags: c, global-variables

Code :

```
int a = 33;
int main()
{
  int a = 40; // local variables always win when there is a conflict between local and global.
  // Here how can i access global variable 'a' having value '33'.
}
```

If you ask : Why would someone want to do above thing? Why [a-zA-Z]* ?

My answer would be : Just to know that 'it is possible to do so'.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827447/how-refer-to-a-local-variable-share-same-name-of-a-global-variable-in-c

Comment: its actually good question but what is  `[a-zA-Z]*` ?

Comment: It means any question starting with 'Why' and ending on '?' e.g. Why you want to access global here? or why blah blah blah blah ?

Comment: @VishalD got it read my answer too get more methods :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this old trick:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 40; // local variables always win when there is a conflict between local and global.

    {
        extern int a;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for beating me by 30 seconds.

Comment: @R.. To be fair, I think I first saw it some time ago in one of your older posts.

Comment: @cnicutar when would you prefer to access via pointer compare to extern keyword **?** I think it will work for global static variable too. correct **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I think it's best to avoid name collisions in the first place, by defensively naming objects and functions your code exports (i.e. everything not `static`). On the other hand, if you already have a pointer there's no need for this trick.

Comment: it didn't work, I'm using DigitalMars compirer

Answer (score 11):

```
int a = 33;
int main()
{
  int a = 40;
  int b;
  {
    extern int a;
    b = a;
  }
  /* now b contains the value of the global a */
}
```

A harder problem is getting `a` if it's `static` with file scope, but that's also solvable:

```
static int a = 33;
static int *get_a() { return &a; }
int main()
{
  int a = 40;
  int b = *get_a();
  /* now b contains the value of the global a */
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `int b = a;  int a = 40;`? Or, might the compiler reorder the lines in this case....

Comment: Indeed you could do that.

Answer (score 4):

**IT IS C++, I OVERLOOKED `C` tag, SORRY !**

```
int a = 100;

int main()
{
    int a = 20;

    int x = a; // Local, x is 20

    int y = ::a; // Global, y is 100

    return 0;
}
```